# Controller Url removing

Tags: magento

i am trying to remove magento controller url in browser address bar.

for example my site have URL **WWW.test.com/** - this page is a home page for my site.
But but i have redirected to login page for customer login. once user type www.test.com site will be redirect to **WWW.test.com/customer/account/login** display login page.

So for Seo purpose i am trying to set "**WWW.test.com/**" as a login content with parent URL (**WWW.test.com/**) . I tried all the ways using **ht access**. but not reflect.

Can any one able to give me better solution for this problem

(Sorry for bad English)
Thanks all

Comment: The easiest approach is to insert login form HTML into your CMS page.

Comment: Hi Jamie . I tried as per your approach. It works fantastic. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tim Looks like you had the solution, could you put it into an answer?

Comment: Done, even though I'm not Jamie :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to insert login form HTML into your CMS page.